# Extract function and dependencies from repository?

Tags: python, file-copying

### Context

Suppose one a repository folder named `some_repo`, with a test file named `test_something.py` in directory `some_repo/tests/` which contains a test class named `class Test_something(unittest.TestCase):` which has a test named: `def test_four(self):`. This `test_four(self)` calls quite a few functions from a few other files in the repository.

### Question

Is it possible to copy the minimum amount of files, functions and classes from repo `a` that are required to run the `test_four(self)` test from the `test_something.py` file, from repository `a` into another folder `b` with a single command?

### Analogy

Kind of like pulling a single thread in a clothing outfit, and getting that entire piece of clothing, without the rest of the outfit.

### Approach

My first guess would be to remove all other test files, and the `__main__.py` file and to run Vulture, however, that seems slightly convoluted, and in my experience Vulture often needs some human guidance.